# Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engin

Tags: key, vision

I recently start to have the following warning initiating vision from a job running on pc.

> 3月 17, 2020 12:11:04 上午 com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
>   資訊: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
>       at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134)
>       at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:113)
>       at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:85)
>       at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:67)
>       at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:135)
>       at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.create(GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.java:117)
>       at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.createStub(ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.java:152)
>       at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:136)
>       at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:117)
>       at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:108)
>       at bennyGoogle.google_vision_api.App.main(App.java:23)

---

OS:ubuntu 18.04
java

### eclipse

[image]